# Is it possible to audit multiple pages with Chrome Developer tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I am trying to find out unused CSS class in my website, and then I found that there is a audit function in Chrome developer tools that will mark unused CSS classes. However, it is only doing one page at a time. Is there a way to make it audit multiple pages so that I can find out CSS classes that are not used in all pages?

I know there is a Firefox plugin Dust-Me that do the job. I am asking just to find if I can do that with Chrome alone, as I am more familiar with Chrome Developer tools.

Answer (score 4):

DevTools only runs against the currently-open page, so my hunch is, no.

You could install the [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) CLI (it uses the same backend for finding unused CSS as DevTools) and then run Lighthouse against a list of URLs via a Bash script.

```
urls=("a.com" "b.com" "c.com")
for url in $urls; do
  lighthouse $url
done
```

Comment: Is there a way to combine the result generated? As said in the question, it is for finding out CSS classes that are not used in all pages.

Answer (score 2):

There's a pretty recent browser extension called [DisCoverage](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/discoverage/bagpgeanndnifdbdacmckipibgkbkpdp) that is supposed to be able to do this. Read the description because version 1.0 of the extension is not able to automate the whole thing and you need to manually export a file for each page you visit and finally combine those files using the same extension.

Hopefully this extension will be improved in the future to be able to collect coverage reports automatically and the allow combining multiple results with a nice UI.

(The extension basically uses Coverage feature of Developer Tools and exports result of coverage for each page into separate files in a single directory. It also contains a feature to combine multiple coverage reports into single final report for viewing the results.)

Comment: So sad, it looks like Google removed the extension recently.

Comment: I really wish Google Chrome had native support for this because extensions cannot track this kind information nicely because of security boundaries. Google killing this extension suggests that they don't even like the idea of extensions trying to do this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame Chrome's Coverage tab doesn't support tracking this across page changes. However, it looks like we can download the report:

[image]

Downloading a report, it looks to be a JSON file. So perhaps we could run it against each page in our site that we want to audit, download each of those reports, then merge them together via some scripting.

Answer (score -1):

DisCoverage is a great tool but be aware that it will not find the json files if you change the filename, got stuck on this 30 min.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).