# Audit an entire website with Lighthouse automatically following links

Tags: lighthouse

Is there a way to make Google Lighthouse to audit an entire website, automatically and recursivelly following the links?

I have searched for a way to do this for some time with no luck. I am even tempted to make such a tool, that wouldn't be so hard. But someone should have figured out the easiest way to accomplish this.

I know I can make a list of urls and run a batch, as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685819/is-it-possible-to-audit-multiple-pages-with-chrome-developer-tools) answer. But It's not practical for big and/or frequently changing websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think unlighthouse is the best option for this. https://unlighthouse.dev/ using this we can audit whole website audit in a single try. disclaimer: it will take some time to generate a report. because i have done this for my website. it took 30 mins for 250 page website. [steps to km](https://www.calcgenie.com/distance-calculators/steps-to-km) and one more thing, for this you need to install node js and create a project in local machine. npx unlighthouse --site hit enter. then it will do the rest, you just need to wait for a while